# Sklearn extra: KMedoids missing 'method' parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn

According to the [Sklearn_extra documentation on KMedoids](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids.html), KMedoids should have the following parameters: `n_clusters`, `metric`, `method`, `init`, `max_iter` and `random_state`. The `method` parameter determines which algorithm to use: `alternate` or `pam`. According to sklearn_extra's [user guide](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cluster.html#k-medoids) these methods are inherently different from each other. For my specific application I want to use the PAM version of K-medoids. However, the `method` parameter seems to have disappeared. When I run an inspect on the KMedoids function:

```
import inspect
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids
inspect.getargspec(KMedoids)
```

I get the following output:

```
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'n_clusters', 'metric', 'init', 'max_iter', 'random_state'], varargs=None, 
keywords=None, defaults=(8, 'euclidean', 'heuristic', 300, None))
```

Here, the `method` parameter is also missing. In the [code of KMedoids](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn_extra/cluster/_k_medoids.html#KMedoids) it appears to be still there. Does anyone know where the parameter has gone? I cannot find anything about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `method` parameter is available in the the latest development version. So uninstall the existing version you have and install the latest directly from github using:

```
pip install https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/archive/master.zip
```

#### Sample (as shown in docs):

```
!pip install https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/archive/master.zip

from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids
import numpy as np

X = np.asarray([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
                [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, method="pam").fit(X)
kmedoids.labels_
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a discrepancy between the latest Github version (and the corresponding documentation) and the latest version available at [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn-extra/) (currently dated 29 March, 2020).

If we install from PyPi with `pip`,

```
pip install scikit-learn-extra
```

and then inspect with

```
print(inspect.getsource(KMedoids))
```

which actually gives the source code of the package in our machine, we get

```
class KMedoids(BaseEstimator, ClusterMixin, TransformerMixin):
    """k-medoids clustering.

    Read more in the :ref:`User Guide <k_medoids>`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n_clusters : int, optional, default: 8
        The number of clusters to form as well as the number of medoids to
        generate.

    metric : string, or callable, optional, default: 'euclidean'
        What distance metric to use. See :func:metrics.pairwise_distances

    init : {'random', 'heuristic', 'k-medoids++'}, optional, default: 'heuristic'
        Specify medoid initialization method. 'random' selects n_clusters
        elements from the dataset. 'heuristic' picks the n_clusters points
        with the smallest sum distance to every other point. 'k-medoids++'
        follows an approach based on k-means++_, and in general, gives initial
        medoids which are more separated than those generated by the other methods.
        
        .. _k-means++: https://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/kMeansPP-soda.pdf

    max_iter : int, optional, default : 300
        Specify the maximum number of iterations when fitting.

    random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional
        Specify random state for the random number generator. Used to
        initialise medoids when init='random'.
```

and

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_clusters=8,
        metric="euclidean",
        init="heuristic",
        max_iter=300,
        random_state=None,
    ):
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.metric = metric
        self.init = init
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.random_state = random_state
```

i.e. the `method` argument is indeed nowhere to be seen.

Installing from Github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra.git
```

and

```
inspect.getfullargspec(KMedoids)
```

gives indeed

```
FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'n_clusters', 'metric', 'method', 'init', 'max_iter', 'random_state'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(8, 'euclidean', 'alternate', 'heuristic', 300, None), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

It is interesting that, in both cases (PyPi and Github), the reported version is exactly the same (`0.1.0b2`); something seems to have gone wrong here in terms of software development good practices...